# Re-populate ehcache value using Spring or scheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I'm using Spring + Ehcache to return a List of Strings:

```
@Cacheable(value = "test", key = "\"myKey"")
    public List<String> getValues()  {
        return getMyValues();
    }
```

Can Ehcache be configued to automatically re-populate the cache when it times out? I'm aware of using `@CacheEvict` to clear the cache but this is a manual operation.

Update :

Here is a possible solution :

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class MyCacheScheduler {

    public void repopulateCache(){

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =
            scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable() {
                public Object call() throws Exception  {
                    myCache.clearCache();
                    myCache.populateCache();
                    return "";
                }
            },
            30,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        try {
            System.out.println("result = " + scheduledFuture.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Autowired
    private MyCacheManagerImpl myCache;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehcache has some built-in solutions for this, however they require some adaptations on the way you work with the cache.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296035/refreshing-caches-while-under-load-with-spring-ehcache/26314041#26314041) for more details.

These constructs are not exposed through Spring's caching abstraction see [point 29.7](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) of the Spring caching documentation.

Comment: thank you, this appears to be exactly what I'm look for. However this caching mechanism is provided as part of Terracotta BigMemory, which is not a free licence ?

Comment: No, the documentation is hosted there, but both of these features are available in the open source distribution.

Comment: "Refresh ahead" requires use of package "net.sf.ehcache.constructs.refreshahead.RefreshAheadCacheFactory" in order to implement the cache loader, this is contained in library ehcache-core . So once I add this library and add configuration as specified at http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/bigmemorymax/api/refresh-ahead this should work ?

Comment: thanks but now I'm experience a new issue, do you mind taking a look ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803277/unable-to-add-cachedecorator-to-ehcache

Answer (score 0):

I am just gonna take a guess on this one:

bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory - Specifies a BootstrapCacheLoader, which is called by a
cache on initialisation to prepopulate itself.

cacheLoaderFactory - Specifies a CacheLoader, which can be used both asynchronously and
      synchronously to load objects into a cache. More than one cacheLoaderFactory element
      can be added, in which case the loaders form a chain which are executed in order. If a
      loader returns null, the next in chain is called.

timeToIdleSeconds Might be a way to keep you data fresh and in sync with the resource underneath

timeToLiveSeconds:
    Sets the time to live for an element before it expires.
    i.e. The maximum time between creation time and when an element expires.
    Is only used if the element is not eternal.
    Optional attribute. A value of 0 means that and Element can live for infinity.
    The default value is 0.

Might be 2 things to look into. All these things I say are settings in the for your cachemananger in the Ehcache.xml file

http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xml

You can Find a ton of information on the website of ehcache (and the forums so you might want to post your question there to get more specialized aid).

Comment: Ehcache forums are outdated and phasing out in favor of StackOverflow