# Unable to add cacheDecorator to ehcache

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

Using "Inline Refresh Ahead" as described at : http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/bigmemorymax/api/refresh-ahead#scheduled-refresh-ahead

I updated my cache entry to :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100"
        overflowToDisk="false" />
    <cache name="myCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="false">

        <cacheDecorator
            class="net.sf.ehcache.constructs.refreshahead.RefreshAheadCacheFactory"
            properties="name=myCacheRefresher,
      timeToRefreshSeconds=200,
      batchSize=10,
      numberOfThreads=4,
      maximumBacklogItems=100,
      evictOnLoadMiss=true" />

    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

But I receive error :

Element  does not allow nested  elements.

So it seems that I have added the cacheDecorator incorrectly ?

Comment: you should read official documentation, the doc you are using is wrong : http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-dec_creating_a_decorator_2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in [the documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-dec_creating_a_decorator_2.html) (cf. @alain.janinm's comment) and [the XSD](http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd) it says

```
....
<xs:element name="cache">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            ...
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                        ref="cacheDecoratorFactory"/>
                                           ^^^^^^^
```

So, your problem is a typo - change

```
<cacheDecorator class="net.sf.ehcache....
```

to

```
<cacheDecoratorFactory class="net.sf.ehcache....
```

and you will be fine.

Cheers,