# How configure Ehcache for recalculation key instead of eviction?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

Let say that object in the cache need to be evicted. But instead of eviction a new value should be calculated and put in the cache. It is important that until old value should be used until new value is generated to guarantee that there is no lock. Can Ehcache be configured for such behavior?

Comment: Well I usually "ovverride" the old value when the new value is generated but I don't use any kind of annotation....

Comment: I mean the scenarion: key evidicted, client try to get value, new value generation starts, client is blocked, generation ends, new value is put into cache, client gets value. So the goal is to remove locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let say that object in the cache need to be evicted.

A cache entry could be evicted due to capacity limits and because the cache entry wasn't requested (hit) recently. Resources need to be freed, nothing about the entry is known any more. When the respective key is requested again, the value needs to be computed again and you cannot hide the additional latency.

A cache entry could expire, e.g. because there is a time to live time span configured. Expiry can happen, while there are lots of incoming requests for that entry. Of course, in this case you may not want that the entry gets removed from the cache, you just want that the value to be refreshed.

Refreshing a value automatically when it expired is called *refresh ahead* or *background refresh*. The answer about that is here:  [Refreshing Caches while under load with Spring/EHCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296035/refreshing-caches-while-under-load-with-spring-ehcache)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "needs to be evicted". The normal Ehcache flow would be the following:

1. Set an entry in the cache
2. Things getting this entry
3. The entry is now obsolete so the application set the new value
4. Things getting this entry (with the new value)

There is no locking involved. Anything getting the entry will directly get the old or the new value without waiting. Unless you are using a loader.